# SYMFONY 3 form validation with choiceType "This value is not valid. "

Tags: php, symfony

I have two entities Contact and Cities no relationship between the two entities, when the user he entered the zip code the combobox is filled automatically using a script ajax there all is well.

At the time of adding to the database, I have this error 'This value is not valid.

```
  class Contact
     {
/**
 * @var integer
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer", nullable=false)
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="IDENTITY")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="content", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $content;



/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="ville", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $ville;

/**
 * @var string
 *
 * @ORM\Column(name="pays", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
 */
private $pays;
```

ContactType:

```
  public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('content',null,array('attr'=>array('class'=>'cp','maxenght'=>5)))
            ->add('ville',ChoiceType::class,array('attr'=>array('class'=>'ville',
            )))
            ->add('pays',null,array('attr'=>array('class'=>'pays')))
            ->add('save',      SubmitType::class)
    ;



}
```

VilleAction:

```
public function villesAction(Request $request, $cp){


if ($request->isXmlHttpRequest()){
     $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $villeCodePostal = $em->getRepository('JTCUserBundle:Villes')-
>findBy(array('villeCodePostal'=>$cp));

    if ($villeCodePostal){

        $villes = array();
        $pays = array();

        foreach ($villeCodePostal as $ville ){

            $villes[] = $ville->getVilleNom();
            $pays[]=$ville->getVilleDepartement();

        }
     //   $ville=$villeCodePostal->getVilleNom();
       // $pays=$villeCodePostal->getVilleDepartement();

    }else{

       $ville=null ;
       // $pays=null ;
    }

    $response = new JsonResponse();


      return $response->setData(array('ville'=>$villes, 'pays'=>$pays));//, 'pays'=>$pays));

 } 
}
```

Comment: Why is Ville a ChoiceType? This type must have a few choices and (i think) Symfony will check that the form field value is one of the choices. Can't you change that to a normal TextType field?

Comment: Yes I think you need some choices, maybe try with some dummy data and replace it with your json response ?

Comment: Hello, I thank you for your answer.
Example: When I enter the postal code, there will be several cities in this postcode, so I have to put the ChoiceType city fields!

Answer (score 0):

Check that you submit something in the profiler. if the value is Submitted try to sublit the same value directly without Ajax. I Think the error comes from the type, $ville expected a string and you submit an integer

Answer (score 0):

I reproduce your code and, i found a solution to your problem.

You could add a function to your VilleEntity:

```
public function __toString(){
       return $this->name;
}
```

And in your ContactType you should replace ville field by this:

```
        ->add('ville', EntityType::class, array(
            'class'=>'AppBundle\Entity\Ville',
            'choice_label'=>'name',
            'label'=>'Ville',
            'multiple'=>false
        ))
```

You can also plug your AJAX refresh. I hope this will help you.

Comment: Hello , thank you for your answer. yes it works but it does not filter that cities that have a postal code entered, I have all the cities in the Choice!

Comment: If you want to dynamically update your form, you must add some FormEvents to your code. You have a documentation [here](http://symfony.com/doc/3.4/form/dynamic_form_modification.html#dynamic-generation-for-submitted-forms). If you want more details or some help i'll can help you.